# What is the logic behind Rails' default restful resource code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, routes, naming-conventions

I'm Learning Rails. Lots of the conventions make great sense. The convention for code that maps to controller actions is odd:

```
//code                  url               controller action
tweets_path             /tweets/          def index
tweet                   /tweet/ID         def show
new_tweet_path          /tweets/new       def new
edit_tweet_path(tweet)  /tweets/ID/edit   def edit
```

Why aren't the automatically generated method helpers done in the same symmetrical way as the controller actions? eg:

```
//code
tweet_index
tweet_show(tweet)
tweet_new
tweet_edit(tweet)
```

I'm so new I'm sure there's a perfectly good reason, I just don't know it yet :)

Comment: Nice question, i think it's really just a convention.. i like the sound of "tweets_path", i expect to see all the tweets in this route and that's what it shows by default. :)

Comment: I found this, which _almost_ explains why: https://blogs.oracle.com/divas/entry/restful_rails_tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two asymmetries here.

The first is plural vs. singular route helpers. Why are some helpers `tweets_*` helpers while others are `tweet_*` helpers?

The answer is that some resource routes are *member* routes and others are *collection* routes. Member routes have to do with an instance of a resource and collection routes have to do with all instances of a resource as a group (unless the resource is singular in which case there are no collection routes). The index action is a *collection* route and the show action is a *member* route.

You can declare your own member and collection routes like this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :tweets do
  member do
    get :duplicate
  end
  collection do
    get :summarize
  end
end
```

This will create two helpers in addition to the standard ones.   Note that Rails will create route helpers that are appropriately singular or plural.

1. a `summarize_tweets_path` helper that does not take a parameter
2. a `duplicate_tweet_path` helper that does

Official docs are [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

The second asymmetry is that the action is left out of the helper for many of the built-in resource actions. I suppose this could have been for brevity, but I don't really know.

**Edit**

After thinking about it, the action name was dropped because there is path overloading in Rails and REST. The '/tweet/:id' path could be the show, update, or delete action depending on the HTTP verb. Basically, the path tells you what you are operating on but not what action to take.

Comment: The plurality mapping to member vs collection makes great sense. I love that convention.

Answer (score 1):

The helper methods are generated in a way that makes them more readable by making them more like parts of sentences. Saying 'Create a link to a new tweet' sounds better than 'Create a link to a tweet new'. It helps to keep this in mind as well when naming any custom actions, using names that fit sentences makes it easier to comprehend and remember since this is how we learn to speak.

Comment: I forget this important part of the Ruby philosophy. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for it not being symmetrical is that the mappings depends on the HTTP action. For example, a GET to /tweets map to the index action, but a POST to /tweets maps to the create action.